# how to map SAML 2 email attribute to external loginInfo email property in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, kentor-authservices

I'm using Kentor AuthService for SAML 2.0 SSO and was able to setup it up and get claims from idp response.

My question is: in my claims, I'm getting the email of a user from the attribute that was set in Idp, but how do I populate the Email property (see the below image) from the External LoginInfo from email attribute in my response?

[image]

My SAML2 Service Provider Metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_f386c1a8-42a2-499e-9e8a-90ca3dd41110" entityID="https://localhost:44300/saml2/sp" cacheDuration="PT1H">
   <SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
      <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localhost:44300/saml2/sp/metadata/Acs" index="0" isDefault="true" />
      <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="https://localhost:44300/saml2/sp/metadata/Acs" index="1" isDefault="false" />
      <AttributeConsumingService index="0" isDefault="false">
         <ServiceName xml:lang="en">saml2p</ServiceName>
         <RequestedAttribute Name="emailAddress" isRequired="true" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" />
      </AttributeConsumingService>
   </SPSSODescriptor>
   <Organization>
      <OrganizationName xml:lang="en-US">Foo</OrganizationName>
      <OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en-US">Foo Inc.</OrganizationDisplayName>
   </Organization>
   <ContactPerson contactType="support">
      <EmailAddress>support@foo.com</EmailAddress>
   </ContactPerson>
</EntityDescriptor>
```